# Json Encode Issues with Objects

Tags: php

```
array(
[key] => Array
    (
        [229] => Tuple Object
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [NAME] => abc
            )
        [233] => Tuple Object
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [NAME] => abcd
            )
           ...
           ...
           ...
     )
 [moreinfo] = 'xyz'
  )
```

issue is when i am using json_encode tuple object is getting lost as all data types like id,name are private.

Following Solution i have found

1. change private variables to public, still i can access the variables as array instead of objects :-(
2. write a wrapper which convert object to array...... an extra effort

can any one suggest a solution in which i can use objects.

Comment: Since there's no obvious way to encode an object with private properties to JSON: no, there's no other way.

Comment: What does "still i can access the variables as array instead of objects" mean? That looks like a [decoding](http://php.net/json_decode) parameter that has nothing to do with your question.